# Create a SelfJoin with has_many

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do a self-join.  I generated this migration to make a
correct primary.  This code works, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do things.

```
class CreateFeedstocks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :feedstocks do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.float :measure_one
      t.float :measure_two
      t.float :measure_three
      t.string :description
      t.integer :primary_feedstock_id, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :feedstocks, :feedstocks,
                     column: :primary_feedstock_id,
                     primary_key: :id
  end
end
```

One feedstock has one `primary_feedstock` and one `primary_feedstock` has
many `feedstocks`.

Comment: Can it be nested? Like primary_feedstock has_many feedstocks, where feedstock has_many other feedstocks?

Comment: @AleksandrK. No, a feedstock belongs to a primary feedstock, but a primary feedstock can have many feedstocks

Comment: Personal opinion - the only thing - consider to make `measure_one`, `measure_two`, `measure_three` as an array field in db. what if you will need 4-5-6?

Comment: @AleksandrK. The measures are actually thickness, width and length. I choose one, two and three because the measure_one could be diameter or thickness, because some feed-stocks has diameter and others has thickness. Thanks for your comment c:

Answer (score 2):

Does the format provided in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) not work for you?

```
# Model ------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Feedstock < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feedstocks,   foreign_key: "primary_feedstock_id"

  belongs_to :primary_feedstock, class_name: "Feedstock"
end

# Migration --------------------------------------------------------------------
class CreateFeedstocks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :feedstocks do |t|
      t.references :primary_feedstock, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** So I'm still not clear on the difference between `add_foreign_key` and `t.references`. According to [this comment on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428414/creating-foreign-key-constraints-in-activerecord#comment16708893_12428677), `t.references` will not create a foreign key constraint, but that was written 5 years ago, and the part of the Guides that the commenter mentioned is no longer there.

The API docs are abundantly clear about `add_foreign_key` creating a foreign key constraint at the database level; unfortunately, they're not so clear about `t.references`.

In any case, you will have to decide for yourself how to design your application. I've heard some people say that depending on ActiveModel is ‘the Rails Way’, but I haven't seen that position stated anywhere in the official docs. Alternately, others will tell you that implementing these checks at the database level is more performant and reliable, and I can't argue with that. I think in the end, the choice comes down to how strictly you believe in Rails' convention-over-configuration philosophy, and whether you're willing to sacrifice a little abstraction for performance and reliability.

**EDIT 2:** It appears that `add_foreign_key` alone is not sufficient to create a table column. You'll need `t.references` either way, followed by either the `foreign_key: true` option or a separate `add_foreign_key` directive.